# What do you call a "singleton" that allows a public constructor for additional instances?

Tags: constructor, singleton, design-patterns, naming

I'm making a class that supports the Singleton use (one instance is available), yet it also supports normal instance use (via a public constructor).

If you only want one, use that one.  If you want 5, new them up.

I clearly can't call this singleton, or some other dev will come along and make my constructor non-public.  What can I call this to indicate how it is to be used?  Naming is hard.

Some guesses for your amusement:
"StaticallyAvailable"?
"ThreadReady"?
"SingletonOptional"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've got a "default instance". You could name your object along those lines.

Comment: That's as good a name as any, if we have to call the construct something.

Comment: This name fit my situation the best, but the other names are very good too!  Thanks StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Usually the point of a singleton is for an object that has an unique instance. If multiple copies of the class can exist, then it means that "oneness" is not a necessary behavior. This is just like any other object.

Probably, the reason why you code it as a Singleton is for the global access. Just call it a global object then.

Answer (score 1):

A Pool ?

(esp if you know how about the instance count early, but want to encapsulate some of the behaviour of constructing / destroying)

Comment: I really like Pool, but I imagine some dev coming in behind me and making it hold all of the instances ever new'd up, instead of the one shared instance.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound like a singleton to me, it sounds like a regular class that always has at least one instance.  Calling this a singleton, and writing the code as though it was one (eg. `private static MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();`) is confusing - decouple the "always present" instance from your class definition somehow.  Make it clear in your implementation that this is a normal class that just happens to always have at least 1 instance around.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a default instance getter.

```
private TheClass defaultInstance;
public Default{ get{ return defaultInstance??(defaultInstance = new TheClass());}
```